# How to display Image inside a loop - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am attempting to display images from Mysql database. I am able to load the image but can not get it to display,  Target here is simply a box layout which I am referring to. This code throws an error

> AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.texture.Texture' object has no attribute 'fbind'

```
row = mycursor.fetchall()
target = self.ids.thebox #This is a simple boxlayout
for value in row:
    if value[9]:
        texture = Texture.create(size=(64, 64))
        image = value[9]
        binary_data = image
        data = io.BytesIO(binary_data)
        img = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
        new_img = Image()
        new_img.texture = img

        target.add_widget(new_img.texture)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

First load an image in form of blob data using normal mysql python and store in a variable, my case called image, you convert it as below to data then add data to CoreImage

```
image = value[9]
data = io.BytesIO(image)
img = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
```

Make sure you use this for your import

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image, CoreImage
```

Next ensure you add a default image within your project folder and call it using widget as follows

```
widget = Image(source = 'a.jpg')
```

Set the texture of widget to img, then add it to your target widget or parent

```
 widget.texture = img
 target.add_widget(widget)
```

The full working code like below:

```
image = value[9] #Add your data
data = io.BytesIO(image)
img = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
widget = Image(source = 'a.jpg')
widget.texture = img
target.add_widget(widget)
```